# How can I transform a list of Strings into another form in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a list of Strings that take the following form:

```
000000
011220
011220
033440
033440
000000
```

I'd like to transform these strings into a List of values that represents each 2x2 block while preserving row information. It is irrelevant whether the data representing each 2x2 block is stored in a list or tuple. For example, the 2x2 block representing the upper left corner could be in one of the following forms:

```
(0, 0, 0, 1)

List((0, 0), (0, 1))

List(0, 0, 0, 1)

List(List(0, 0), List(0, 1))
```

---

The Scala code below performs the prescribed transformation, but it seems overly complex. I can break up some of the functionality into separate functions, but I cannot see how this code can be converted into a simpler form like a for-comprehension.

> **NOTE:** I've simplified the list of values for brevity.

```
scala> val data = List("000000", "011220", "033440")
data: List[String] = List(000000, 011220, 033440)

scala> val values = (data map { _.toList.sliding(2).toList } sliding(2) map { _.transpose } map { _ map { _.flatten } }).toList
values: List[List[List[Char]]] = List(List(List(0, 0, 0, 1), List(0, 0, 1, 1), List(0, 0, 1, 2), List(0, 0, 2, 2), List(0, 0, 2, 0)), List(List(0, 1, 0, 3), List(1, 1, 3, 3), List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(2, 2, 4, 4), List(2, 0, 4, 0)))
```

For clarity, I've relabeled some of the lists with 'Row' and 'Block', but they do not represent any concrete classes. They are simply monikers to present a more meaningful view of the output above.

```
values: List[Row[Block[Char]]] = List(Row(Block(0, 0, 0, 1), Block(0, 0, 1, 1), ...), Row(Block(0, 1, 0, 3), Block(1, 1, 3, 3), ...))
```

I am relatively new to Scala and I'd like to know if the code represented above a good way to implement this transformation or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: To get a more concise syntax to do what you require, one possibility is to create a custom type which will allow you to manipulate your data more easily. To me, a type which would mimic a matrix along with rich matrix operations could lead to a more concise syntax for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think it;'s not particularly complex. It's also (as this style can encourage) not very obvious, either. I think it would be good to define classes (as @I.K. suggests) and short methods to make it clearer what this transform achieves

Comment: Are there good intermediate resources for defining new types in Scala? I assume you are not referring simply to classes, but to types which override traits utilized by containers in the Scala base libraries. For instance, [GenericTraversableTemplate](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate) provides the implementation for the transpose operation. Implementing a 'type' that uses this trait is perhaps what you are talking about. Is there good reference material for doing that, or is the school of hard knocks best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to accomplish the task using a for-comprehension.

```
(for {
    // Create the pair of strings for each 'row'. For example: List(011220, 033440) 
    List(row1, row2) <- data.sliding(2)
  } yield (
    for {
      // Create the sequence of values representing a block.
      Seq((a1, a2),(b1, b2)) <- row1 zip row2 sliding(2)
    } yield (a1, b1, a2, b2) ).toVector
).toList
```

For clarity, each 2x2 block is a tuple, each row is a Vector and the entire set of rows is a List. The results in the REPL are below:

```
scala> val data = List("000000", "011220", "033440")
data: List[String] = List(000000, 011220, 033440)

scala> (for { List(row1, row2) <- data.sliding(2) } yield (for { Seq((a1, a2),(b1, b2)) <- row1 zip row2 sliding(2) } yield (a1, b1, a2, b2) ).toVector ).toList
res1: List[Vector[(Char, Char, Char, Char)]] = List(Vector((0,0,0,1), (0,0,1,1), (0,0,1,2), (0,0,2,2), (0,0,2,0)), Vector((0,1,0,3), (1,1,3,3), (1,2,3,4), (2,2,4,4), (2,0,4,0)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it this way (the `.toList` are essentially here to see the results instead of `non-empty iterator`) :

```
scala> val values = data.map(_.sliding(2).toList)  // create a sliding window over consecutive characters
                        .sliding(2).toList         // slide over consecutive rows
                        .flatMap { case List(row1, row2) => row1 zip row2 } // zip rows together, creating the blocks
values: List[(String, String)] = List((00,01), (00,11), (00,12), (00,22),
                                      (00,20), (01,03), (11,33), (12,34),
                                      (22,44), (20,40))
```

Comment: Also reasonable but in what way is it better than the OP's code?

Comment: @Paul : Mostly I find `.map { case List(row1, row2) => row1 zip row2 }` easier to read/reason about than `map { _.transpose } map { _ map { _.flatten } }`.

Comment: OK, Yours was the approach I was using until I saw you'd beaten me to an answer, so I'd probably agree, but I think it's worth pointing out why you're offering a alternative

Comment: That last `map`/`flatten` can be `flatMap`?

Comment: @Paul : You're right, I'll change that, thanks. (I actually added the `.flatten` on SO directly and not in the REPL, didn't really think it through)

Comment: I do that all the time. It's a sort of visual optimisation task for me to change them back to a flatMap...